# How to communicate with an isolate performing a blocking operation in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-isolates

In a work for desktop flutter application (linux), I need to do some intensive computing task into an isolate. But, while this isolate is performing this long operation, it is not reading incoming messages (which seems logic). 
I would like to still be able to communicate with it while it is performing.

```dart
  ReceivePort rPort;
  SendPort sPort;
  Isolate isolate;

void main() {
  rPort = ReceivePort();
  isolate = await Isolate.spawn(entryPoint, receivePort.sendPort);
  sPort = await rPort.first;
  sendMessage("perform"); // this is being processed
  sendMessage("controlMessage"); // this is being processed after the perform has ended
}

void sendMessage(String msg) {
  ReceivePort localReceivePort = ReceivePort();
  sendPort.send([msg, localReceivePort.sendPort]);
}

void entryPoint(SendPort sendPort)
{
 ReceivePort receivePort = ReceivePort();
 sendPort.send(receivePort.sendPort);

 receivePort.listen((message) {
   String data = msg[0];
   SendPort reply = msg[1];
   print(data);
   if(data == "perform") performBlockingOperation();
   else if(data == "controlMessage") controlPerformance();
   repy.send("something"); 
 });

}
```

I tried many options : making the performBlockingOperation async, but this doesn't seem to work.
Even trying to create a native thread inside the isolate returns

> ../../third_party/dart/runtime/vm/runtime_entry.cc: 3331: error:
>   Cannot invoke native callback outside an isolate.

Is there a way to achieve what I am trying ?

Comment: *"I would like to still be able to communicate with it while it is performing."* - to be clear: you want to be in some big computation loop in your `Isolate` and still to receive incoming messages? or you want to get next queued message *after* one "big computation task loop" is done?

Comment: First option, I want to be in some big computation loop in Isolate, and still receive incoming messages.

Comment: well, it is impossible, unless you add some checkpoints in your loop checking if some new messages arrived - but i really doubt that you can do that (or you can?)

Comment: Yes I can, the long computing function is just a long loop. I can put whatever I want inside the loop.

Comment: so add in your loop `await Future(() {});` to give some chance for `receivePort.listen()` to do its work

Comment: Do you mean to writte `await Future(() {listenAndDoSomething});` ? 
Because with empty Future statement it doesn't seem to work here (I thought an empty await Future as you wrote would then pause execution to give the Isolate listener time to listen). I'll keep investigating.

Comment: see https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/qJZF64R4y7/

Comment: The few tests I ran aren't working differently than my previous implementation. But I notice that even a simple `print` inside the performance loop doesn't print, which is weird. So I might have another implementation issue. Looking at this, and I'll return as soon as I can fix it.

Comment: so you dont see `print('step $i');` ? how come? have you  spawned the isolate successfully?

Comment: Yes the isolate is running. 
The code is : 
`while(performAudioBlock()) {
 print("step $i");
}`.

Comment: first run my code without any changes, make sure you call `channel.sink.add('input data')` from the main thread during the first 10 steps of isolate loop - of course you can call `channel.sink.add` multiple times

Comment: Yes I did that. I'm pretty sure it is coming from somewhere else than the Isolate. Don't have time to do this now, but I will do tests tomorow ! Thanks for your help

Comment: Your code works fine here. The problem for me may be that `while(performAudioBlock()){}` overflows the isolate event loop. Depending on audio block size, it computes 512 double 40 times per seconds.  Is there a way to see if that overflow is happening ?

Comment: Because nothing inside the while loop is actually processed.

Comment: I had a typo somewhere in the ffi of the native API I am wrapping,  so it was wrapping the wrong function - so it was performing all audio (like 20 seconds) rather than only one audio block before entering inside the loop. Works fine now with your isolate channel. Thanks for helping !

Comment: great!, i think it could be done easier using `SchedulerBinding` but if the current approach works...

Comment: And do you think it would be more efficient in computing time ?

Answer (score 2):

Making the computation asynchronous is the right first step.
The second step is to actually yield control at some points during the computation.

Then insert some `await Future.delayed(Duration.zero);` statements in your computation code that is blocking everything else. Not too deep in the computation, because it does introduce a delay, but often enough that your isolate gets a chance to check for new events occasionally.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I'm not sure how to do with the second step. Is that about the yield statement ? And is it inside the performance function or control (main isolate) ?

Comment: No `yield` statements needed. The `await` statement should be inside the "performance function", the code that is running and preventing the isolate from doing anything else. By adding a delay inside that code, a delay long enough to allow the event loop to check for other events, you ensure that other code can also get a chance to run.